# How to check if a string contains a date in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, date, simpledateformat

How do I check if a string contains a date of this form:

> Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:36pm EST

The data I'm working with contains a ton of strings. But the type of string I'm looking for contains a 2 or 3 word name and a date. I'm checking for dates to identify these types of strings.

I've figured out the simpleDateFormat for this type of date.

```
String string1 = "Rahul Chowdhury Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:37pm EST";
String string2 = "Aritra Sinha Nirmal Friday, April 1, 2016 at 10:16pm EDT";    

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mmaa z");
```

But I have no idea how to proceed further.

I'm guessing regex might work but I don't know how to implement that when the length of the names of months/days vary. i.e. 'May' is much shorter than 'December'.

*I'm wondering if there is a solution using regex or a simpler solution to this.*

**I know there are other threads asking similar questions, but they don't answer my question.**

Comment: Use `format.parse(string)` If the format not match it will throw ParseException

Comment: A regex to check for days of the week and months is probably going to very long.  Can you describe better the actual problem which you think requires checking strings to see if they be dates?

Comment: Why? Just try to parse it as a date and catch the exception. No point in duplicating all that effort.

Comment: The strings have more than just dates. So Strings, which match my criteria but also have other words in it, will throw an exception and I'll miss them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could first check the presence of your date with a regex:

```
\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\s+at\s+\d+:\d+(pm|am)\s+\w{3,4}
```

This regex matches both

```
Rahul Chowdhury Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:37pm EST
Aritra Sinha Nirmal Friday, April 1, 2016 at 10:16pm EDT
```

https://regex101.com/r/V0dAf8/2/

When you found the match in your text then you could use `SimpleDateFormat` to check if it is well formed.

```
String input = "Rahul Chowdhury Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:37pm EST";
String regex = "(\\w+,\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d+\\,\\s+\\d+\\s+at\\s+\\d+:\\d+(pm|am)\\s+\\w{3,4})";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This will print:

```
Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:37pm EST
```

Comment: I love you. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you will at least want `\w{3,4}` at the end; some time zone abbreviations are four letters. You may or may not need to accommodate further time zone names like `Z` or `+01:00`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `Regex` you may do something like this (I know it is a pain but just a different approach).

```
public class ParseDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "Rahul Chowdhury Sunday, January 15, 2012 at 7:36pm EST";
        //Pattern: "Fullname EEEEE, MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mmaa z"
        String dateComponents[] = date.split(",");
        String fullName = dateComponents[0].substring(0, dateComponents[0].lastIndexOf(" "));
        String dayText = dateComponents[0].substring(dateComponents[0].lastIndexOf(" "));
        String month = dateComponents[1].trim().split(" ")[0];
        String dayNumber = dateComponents[1].trim().split(" ")[1];
        String year = dateComponents[2].split("at")[0];
        String time = dateComponents[2].split("at")[1].trim().split(" ")[0];
        String zone =dateComponents[2].split("at")[1].trim().split(" ")[1];

        // if you want to go further 
        String hour = time.split(":")[0];
        String minutes = time.split(":")[1].substring(0,2);
        String aa = time.split(":")[1].substring(2,4);


        System.out.println(fullName + " " + dayText + " " + month + " " + dayNumber + " " + year + " " + time + " " + zone);
        System.out.println(hour + " " + minutes + " " + aa);
    }


}
```

**Output**

```
Rahul Chowdhury Sunday January 15  2012  7:36pm EST
7 36 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test it using the simpleDateFormat parse method. to continue your code, surround the code with a try/catch, for instance:

```
try {
    Date date = format.parse(string);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        //the string is not applicable to the date format
}
```

If the date is a string which follows the format guidelines in the SimpleDateFormat, the Date will be created successfully.

Comment: The strings I'm using contain more than just dates. So this will always throw an exception.

Comment: If a string contains more than just the date, it will still parse it and create a date if the string has the date first and the rest of the string as a suffix. So for the string:
"January 15, 2012 at 7:37pm EST, Rahul Chowdhury Sunday" It will work. If flipping the order it too tricky, you can parse only the substring - simply run:
 try {

        Date date = format.parse(string.substring(string.indexOf(",")+1);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        //the string is not applicable to the date format
    }